# Cafe brulot in emily post's etiquette

Tags: coffee, spices, alcohol, beverages, fire

I've searched everywhere and I've been unable to find a copy of the recipe I found in the 1938 or so edition of Etiquette by Emily Post. She describes a drink that is served flaming mixed with spices, and as far as I can find, it's probably cafe brulot.

As I have been unable to locate my copy, can anybody point me in the right direction, or do they have the recipe from the book?

Comment: A quick internet search "Café Brulot" returns a number of recipes

Comment: I found plenty of recipes, and the article describes a cafe brulot, so apparently I'm looking for a modification thereof. These were described as being for a small gathering and the cups themselves held the flames without the display.

Answer (score 1):

A quick internet search "Café Brulot" returns a number of recipes.

There is even a scan of"Good Taste Today" by Emily Post in the St. Petersburg Times Feb 6 1938) that describes the Café Brulot (not a recipe).

http://news.google.com/newspapers?id=nx9PAAAAIBAJ&sjid=Wk0DAAAAIBAJ&pg=3267%2C872400

Answer (score 0):

Middle column - near the bottom of the page.  Identified as Cafe Brulot.  Hope this is what you were looking for.

http://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=888&dat=19380206&id=nx9PAAAAIBAJ&sjid=Wk0DAAAAIBAJ&pg=3267,872400